# how to display correct or wrong data in different ways

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I am trying use this query to display multi values, but the returned set contains right and wrong data. Because some data doesn't have column, I want it to be display 0, how could I achieve that. Currently, it just ignores those data that doesn't contain column.

Example:

```
EmployeeID   Number of Records

1111111               2

222222                3

4444444               0
```

Currently, it just gave me like this:

```
EmployeeID   Number of Records

 1111111               2

 222222                3

select EmployeeID, NumberofRecords 
where EmployeeNationalIDAlternateKey in ( @EmployeeID )
Group    by EmployeeID
```

Comment: Can you give schema of your tables? In your query you are missing from clause.

Answer (score 0):

If Employee Table Contains list of all employees and EmployeeRecord contains list of all the individual record of all the employees then

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, ISNULL(ER.EmpRcd, 0) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM Employee E 
LEFT JOIN (Select EmployeeID, Count(*) EmpRcd FROM Employee GROUP BY EmployeeID) ER
ON E.EmployeeID = ER.EmployeeID
```